# Waiting for images loaded and delay if faster than expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When waiting for a bunch of images loading, I want to set a min-wait-time say 200ms. Which means, no matter how fast the images loaded, I will wait for that time, so:

> If images loaded in 100ms, I wait for 200ms
>
> If images loaded in 150ms, I wait for 200ms
>
> If images laoded in 300ms, I wait for 300ms

Is this possible?

Currently I use `imagesLoaded` to detect when images loaded, it is usually faster than I expect

```
        container.imagesLoaded(function() {
            container.fadeIn();
        });
```

Comment: Can you not simply hide a wrapping element at first, and then show it after a delay? That way if they load quickly they won't be visible right away. If they load slower, then you fallback to your normal scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe a simple call to `setTimeout` should do the trick. It will wait 200ms and then keep waiting for the images if they still aren't loaded:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  container.imagesLoaded(function() {
        container.fadeIn();
    });
}, 200);
```